# Sending Outlook mail to multiple distribution lists in Python

Tags: python, email, outlook, win32com

I'm using Python and win32com.client to send Outlook mails to multiple distribution lists like so:

```
olMailItem = 0x0
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = "This is subject"
newMail.To = "abc@company.com"
newMail.CC = "samplegrp1; samplegrp2"   # offending statement
//some html processing in mail content
newMail.Send()
```

The above code works as I'm able to send to a single group using:

```
newMail.CC = "samplegrp1"
```

but when I try to send to multiple groups (the offending statement above), I receive the following error:

```
>     return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(61557, LCID, 1, (24, 0), (),)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Out
look', 'Outlook does not recognize one or more names. ', None, 0, -2147467259),
None)
```

I tried using comma instead of semicolon, using + operator, etc. but to no avail.

If anyone can help, thanks.

Comment: Does it work if `newMail.CC = "samplegrp2"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from win32com.client.gencache import EnsureDispatch
from win32com.client import constants

outlook = EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = outlook.CreateItem(constants.olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = "This is subject"

samplegrp1 = newMail.Recipients.Add("samplegrp1")
samplegrp2 = newMail.Recipients.Add("samplegrp2")
samplegrp1.Type = constants.olCC
samplegrp3.Type = constants.olCC
newMail.Recipients.ResolveAll()
```

This is documented on [How to: Specify Different Recipient Types for a Mail Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184598%28v=office.14%29.aspx).