# Python Is there a way to send email to existing mailing list?

Tags: python, email, smtp, win32com

So I am writing a python script to send an email out once the script finishes running.

I want to be able to send it to a group. For example, we have a mailing group of "IT". Currently in my code below, I can send to individual or even multiple people, but I have to specify each one:

```
mail.To = 'example1@example.ca;example2@example.ca'
```

Is there a way I can send it to the group IT? This would be preferable if people are added or removed from the group I wouldn't have to rebuild this script every time.

Comment: Have you tried to do `mail.To = "name_gr_IT"`?

Comment: Yes that doesn't work. The only groups it works is if the group has an email attached to it (e.g. IT@example.com). For now I will have to use that

Comment: I see, have you tried the method in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24073104/9274732)?